# webpack AOT cannot use functions

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-nativescript

I integrated webpack into my angular2 application.

I have encountered an error:

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function

Some of them could be fixed by reworking this

```
{provide: MY_SERVICE, useFactory: () => newService(api), deps: [Api]}
```

to:

```
export function newService(api: Api) {new Service(api)} 
...   
{provide: MY_SERVICE, useFactory: newService, deps: [Api]}
```

But how do I solve importing a module which requires .forRoot?

```
TNSFontIconModule.forRoot({'flaticon': 'flaticon.css'})
```

Comment: And what does happen with a module which requires .forRoot? Are you sure that the problem can be extrapolated to all modules and not just TNSFontIconModule?

Comment: I get the same error - function calls are not supported. I think I need to work around using a function in the ngModule decorator, like I did with the examples above. I checked, any module requiring .forRoot will throw the same error

Comment: Which modules did you try? Does router module cause the error? I would expect that this may happen with modules that weren't written (or published to NPM) with AoT in mind.

Comment: It could be that the `.forRoot()` method is indeed not prepared for AoT. [This comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262#issuecomment-246131241) seems to indicate that things should be kept simple there.

Comment: So it seems like I am not doing it wrong, I either have to rewrite the plugins to make them ready or stop using AOT, right?